# How to set Content-Type header in Elastigo

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I received this error when trying to insert data into elasticsearch using elastigo.  The error is

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}
```

Does anyone know how to set content type header to elastigo?

I think that Elastigo doesn't work with elasticsearch 6.4.3, should I change to olivere package to make requests to elasticsearch?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo/issues/297

Answer (score 0):

> should I change to olivere package to make requests to elasticsearch?

yes